# Percent of non-mutually exclusive x AND y

Tags: percentages

There are x people in a survey.

y% of people checked box A

z% of people checked box B

It is possible to check BOTH boxes

What percentage of x people checked both boxes?

Am I correct in saying that this question is unanswerable without more information?

Comment: Is it possible to check no boxes? Are there more options than just A, B?

Comment: It is possible to check no boxes. There are other boxes as well, but they have no bearing on A and B

Comment: Then you should be able to easily find a concrete example where $ y $ and $ z $ don't uniquely determine the number of people who checked both boxes.

Comment: Could you give an example with numbers please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of finding box $A$ checked is $y$. The probability of finding box $B$ checked is $z$. *If* whether or not a person checks $A$ is *independent* of whether or not a person checks $B$, then the probability of finding both $A$ and $B$ checked is $x=y(z)$. If those two events are in fact dependent, then the answer is not so clear... you would need more information.

Comment: Thank you. In this example, we're  dealing with probabilities, not concrete outcomes correct?

Comment: Yeah, you can effectively treat the proportions of people who do such and such as  probabilities and work solely with those

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated